# Reactivity to an array element based on object property

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

I am getting student details in summary form, just name and surname. I am passing the response to an array in data: `data: function(){ return{ studsSummary:[] }}`. I am using this stud array in a v-for to create the students dynamically like this: `<div>{{studSummary.name}}</div>`.

On selecting a student, I am loading the student details in detailed form beneath the summary area. The detailed details have an object inside data with corresponding fields. Let's say just name and surname only for my question. So in data I also have `studDetailed : { name: '', surname: ''}`. Further more these are now bound to a textfield through `v-model='studDetailed.name'`. Now since studsSummary[0].name = studDetailed.name I want the former to react to the latter and have any changes reflect in the summary also as I type in the textfield.

What do I have to change please to make this work? I have then tried `this.$set(this.studsSummary[0], 'name', this.studDetailed.name)` to bind the two (it's ultimately what I want), but that didn't work.